# how to get projections in mongodb with group operator

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I have a table with columns Column1 & Column2 which looks like this

```
    Colum1 Column2 
     A       1
     A       2
     A       3
     B       2
     B       4
     B       6
```

If I perform following SQL in MYSQL

```
      SELECT Column1, Column2, count(*) from Table group by Column1;
```

Result is

```
  Column1 Column2 Count(*)
   A         1         3
   B         2         3
```

I want to execute similar query on MONGODB

I tried

```
 QUERY1: db.table.aggregate({$group: {_id:"$Column1", count:{$sum:1}} })
 QUERY2: db.table.aggregate({$project: {column1:1, column2:1}}, {$group: {_id:"$Column1", count:{$sum:1}} })
```

However the result for Query2 is same as Query1, It seems like you can not populate fields other than mentioned in $group column.

**Is there a way to populate other fields in mongodb along with $group operator ?**

Comment: Docs have an example that I believe is what you want: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I read the mysql query correctly, and I don't understand why this is particularly useful, but `$first` seems to accomplish the same thing.

However, as mentioned in the [`$first` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first), the outcome depends on the sorting so you should include a sorting criterion.

Data (column names shortened for brevity)

```
> db.foo.insert({"C1" : "A", "C2" : 1});
> db.foo.insert({"C1" : "A", "C2" : 2});
> db.foo.insert({"C1" : "A", "C2" : 3});
> db.foo.insert({"C1" : "B", "C2" : 2});
> db.foo.insert({"C1" : "B", "C2" : 4});
> db.foo.insert({"C1" : "B", "C2" : 6});
```

Aggregation Query

```
> db.foo.aggregate({$group: {_id:"$C1", C2: { $first: "$C2" }, count:{$sum:1}} })
```

Results

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "B",
                        "C2" : 2,
                        "count" : 3
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "A",
                        "C2" : 1,
                        "count" : 3
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: MySQL query is correct, My infrastructure has multiple server with friendly names say Server1, Server2 .... each server has multiple hostnames and multiple IP, now the MySQL query which I wrote gives me Server friendly name, number of IPs attached to it and a pair of IPAddress and Hostname to access That Server.                                                                  Thanks for the reply, I will try this in Mongo. Appreciated help.